# Elixir or Erlang prompt for password with hidden input

Tags: erlang, command-line-interface, elixir, erlang-escript

I'm writing a CLI in elixir, how can I prompt the user for a password, without displaying the input in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are some problems with this. Currently the best solution seems to be to repeatedly clear the input in a loop, as implemented in the Hex package manager:

https://github.com/hexpm/hex/blob/1523f44e8966d77a2c71738629912ad59627b870/lib/mix/hex/utils.ex#L32-L58

Comment: Fair enough. There might not be a good platform independent way to do it via the VM.

Comment: You might also have some luck using `:io.get_password` from OTP, but I remember that I couldn't get it to work properly. I think it follows a similar approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using the Erlang `:io.get_password()` function, e.g.

```
IO.write("What is your password?")

password = :io.get_password()
           |> List.to_string()
```

Note that `IO.write/1` is preferable to using `Mix.shell().info()` for the prompt because the `info` function will add a newline, which is usually not what you want in a prompt.

Also be advised that `:io.get_password()` returns input as a charlist, so you will probably want to convert it to a binary as demonstrated above.

I wrote a package that utilizes the above technique: https://hex.pm/packages/cowrie

Answer (score 0):

Just borrow the functionality directly from `Mix.Tasks.Hex`, by writing some code like the following,

```
some_pass = 
  Mix.Tasks.Hex.password_get("Password: ") 
  |> String.replace_trailing("\n","")
```

And if you are requesting the password in a task, and don't want to keep asking for it over and over, you can save it in an environment variable like this,

```
:os.putenv(String.to_charlist("SECRET_PASSWORD"), String.to_charlist(some_pass))
```

And, of course, retrieve it with:

```
System.get_env("SECRET_PASSWORD")
```